# "No module named _scproxy" on OSX

Tags: python, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I'm on OSX 10.6 with pre-installed python 2.6 and would like to install python packages via easy_install or setup.py (in a downloaded package). In my case I'm trying to install MySQLdb. In both cases I get a stack trace which ends like so:

```
...
File  "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 21, in <module>
    from setuptools.package_index import PackageIndex, parse_bdist_wininst
File  "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/package_index.py", line 2, in <module>
   import sys, os.path, re, urlparse, urllib2, shutil, random, socket, cStringIO
File  "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python/framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 111, in <module>
   from urllib import (unwrap, unquote, splittype, splithost, quote,
File  "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 1335, in <module>
   from _scproxy import _get_proxy_settings, _get_proxies
ImportError: No module named _scproxy
```

The python installation is the unmodified pre-installed version 2.6.1 except that I added the source files to the lib folder. A "find /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/ -name *scproxy*" does not yield any results.

How can I install the missing module?

Comment: In order to execute Jacob Oscarson's recipe (below) I needed to install the OSX developer tools (gcc and stuff). I'm not sure what else I did, but afterwards I could use setuptools (without compiling python). Thanks anyways for your effort, Jacob!

Comment: For people showing up here in 2015, Yosemite fails to build sharedmods because of this: http://hamelot.co.uk/programming/osx-gcc-dispatch_block_t-has-not-been-declared-invalid-typedef/  (object.h:143).  Make that edit, "make sharedmods" and continue as before.

Answer (score 8):

**Background**

`_scproxy` is a Mac-specific urllib helper interfacing with OS-specific libraries to do HTTP requests. It seems to be missing on my system too (10.6.7). Preliminary, I think it looks like a problem with the system Python build (I can't find anything that looks like it under `/System/Libraries`).

**Hack-o-rama solution**

It's (sort of) possible to install the missing module. But first a bit of advice:

You Shouldn't<sup>TM</sup> mess too much with your system Python installation. Do yourself a favour by learning to use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv/), and apply potentially dangerous operations on new, fresh virtualenv's. That way you're system wont be affected by installation of problematic packages.

Anyway: stock Python on Snow Leopard is 2.6.1. I did my experiments with the most recent 2.6, 2.6.6, a marginably safer way would be to download that instead. My experience is however that varying dot releases work just fine together.

Anyway, I downloaded 2.6.6 in my `~/src` directory like this:

```
~/src/ext/python$ wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.6/Python-2.6.6.tgz
~/src/ext/python$ tar zxf Python-2.6.6.tgz
~/src/ext/python$ cd Python-2.6.6
~/src/ext/python$ ./configure
```

*console spams like crazy*

```
~/src/ext/python$ make sharedmods
```

*hopefully no errors, more console spamming*

Locate the newly built `_scproxy.so`:

```
~/src/ext/python/Python-2.6.6$ find . -name '_scproxy.so'
./build/lib.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.6/_scproxy.so # <- exact path may vary
```

You can now copy your `_scproxy.so` to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynlo
ad` (and then remember that there's a home-built somewhat alien module in you system Python). Or, much better, add it to the `lib/python2.6/` subdirectory of a virtualenv. After doing these things, I could import _scproxy in the manner indicated in your traceback:

```
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from _scproxy import _get_proxy_settings, _get_proxies
>>>
```

This is a strong indication that installing packages via a method requiring `urllib` requests utlizing `_scproxy` will work. From there on you have continue on your own, though, since I don't want to test-install MySQL itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your extensive instructions. Sounds reasonable to me. Unfortunately, I cannot try them until next week (don't yet have a compiler installed and stuff like that).

Comment: While you can certainly build _scproxy that Apple left out, the Python 2.6.1 in OS X 10.6 is pretty old at this point.  You may be better off using a newer Python 2.6 or, better, Python 2.7.  Installers are available from python.org:  http://python.org/download/