# MathSage unable to compile _scproxy

Tags: gcc, installation, failed-installation

On macOS 10.12, I am getting the following error while attempting to build MathSage (`make && make clean`):

```
Successfully installed python2-2.7.10.p1
Deleting temporary build directory
/Applications/SageMath/local/var/tmp/sage/build/python2-2.7.10.p1
Finished installing python2-2.7.10.p1.spkg
sage-logger 'sage-spkg atlas-3.10.2.p2' '/Applications/SageMath/logs/pkgs/atlas-3.10.2.p2.log'
Found local metadata for atlas-3.10.2.p2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/SageMath/build/bin/sage-download-file", line 27, in <module>
    from sage_bootstrap.cmdline import SageDownloadFileApplication
  File "/Applications/SageMath/build/bin/../sage_bootstrap/cmdline.py", line 28, in <module>
    from sage_bootstrap.download import Download
  File "/Applications/SageMath/build/bin/../sage_bootstrap/download.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sage_bootstrap.compat import urllib
  File "/Applications/SageMath/build/bin/../sage_bootstrap/compat.py", line 23, in <module>
    import urllib
  File "/Applications/SageMath/local/lib/python/urllib.py", line 1414, in <module>
    from _scproxy import _get_proxy_settings, _get_proxies
ImportError: No module named _scproxy
make[2]: *** [/Applications/SageMath/local/var/lib/sage/installed/atlas-3.10.2.p2] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2

real    154m30.485s
user    93m39.621s
sys 12m38.882s
***************************************************************
Error building Sage.
```

As seen, it is complaining that "scproxy" is not found.

Indeed, looking back further up in the log, I find this error when MathSage is (apparently?) attempting to compile _scproxy.c:

```
building '_scproxy' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/Mac
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/Mac/Modules
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Applications/SageMath/local/var/tmp/sage/build/python2-2.7.10.p1/include -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wno-unused -I/Applications/SageMath/local/include -I. -IInclude -I./Include -I/usr/local/include -I/Applications/SageMath/local/var/tmp/sage/build/python2-2.7.10.p1/src/Include -I/Applications/SageMath/local/var/tmp/sage/build/python2-2.7.10.p1/src -c ./Mac/Modules/_scproxy.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/./Mac/Modules/_scproxy.o
In file included from /usr/include/Availability.h:190:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:65,
                 from Include/Python.h:33,
                 from ./Mac/Modules/_scproxy.c:5:
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDateFormatter.h:53:34: error: expected ',' or '}' before '__attribute__'
     kCFISO8601DateFormatWithYear API_AVAILABLE(macosx(10.12), ios(10.0), watchos(3.0), tvos(10.0)) = (1UL << 0),
                                  ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDateFormatter.h:80:126: error: 'introduced' undeclared here (not in a function)
 CFDateFormatterRef CFDateFormatterCreateISO8601Formatter(CFAllocatorRef allocator, CFISO8601DateFormatOptions formatOptions) API_AVAILABLE(macosx(10.12), ios(10.0), watchos(3.0), tvos(10.0));
                                                                                                                              ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFURL.h:777:39: error: 'deprecated' undeclared here (not in a function)
 const CFStringRef kCFURLLabelColorKey API_DEPRECATED("Use NSURLLabelColorKey", macosx(10.6, 10.12), ios(4.0, 10.0), watchos(2.0, 3.0), tvos(9.0, 10.0));
                                       ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFURL.h:777:39: error: 'message' undeclared here (not in a function)
 const CFStringRef kCFURLLabelColorKey API_DEPRECATED("Use NSURLLabelColorKey", macosx(10.6, 10.12), ios(4.0, 10.0), watchos(2.0, 3.0), tvos(9.0, 10.0));
                                       ^
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/AuthSession.h:32:0,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/Security.h:43,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Headers/SCPreferences.h:35,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Headers/SystemConfiguration.h:124,
                 from ./Mac/Modules/_scproxy.c:6:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/Authorization.h:192:7: error: variably modified 'bytes' at file scope
  char bytes[kAuthorizationExternalFormLength];
       ^
./Mac/Modules/_scproxy.c: In function 'get_proxy_settings':
./Mac/Modules/_scproxy.c:67:50: warning: the comparison will always evaluate as 'true' for the address of 'kSCPropNetProxiesExcludeSimpleHostnames' will never be NULL [-Waddress]
     if (&kSCPropNetProxiesExcludeSimpleHostnames != NULL) {
                                                  ^
```

It doesn't look like the problem discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647023/no-module-named-scproxy-on-osx), because that has to do with a missing System copy of _scproxy. (I see

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_scproxy.so
```

on my system.) And it doesn't look to me either like the problem discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30903123/importerror-no-module-named-scproxy), because that has to do a file named `/usr/include/dispatch/object.h` being Objective-C, whereas the error above complains about something going wrong in `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDateFormatter.h`.

However, it may yet have to do with my version of gcc. Here's what I get when I run `gcc -v`:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Also, the second post that I quoted recommends using the Sage gcc compiler, as achieved by "including" the `SAGE_INSTALL_GCC=yes` option. I don't really know what I'm doing here, I tried running

```
make clean && make SAGE_INSTALL_GCC=yes
```

instead of the usual `make clean && make`, and it ran into the same error.

Any advice?